# No module named 'P2PPlugin'

Tags: p2p

Trying to add PeerMessage plug-in on ZeroNet I recieve this error:

```
Displaying 1 of 1 lines found in the last 326kB of the log file. (326kB total)
[2021-09-05 13:03:18,463] ERROR PluginManager Plugin PeerMessage load error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'P2PPlugin' in PluginManager.py line 138 > PeerMessage/__init__.py line 1
```

After running ZeroNet you can download PeerMessage at this zite (ZN address):
http://127.0.0.1:43110/kxonet.bit/?/plugins

Click on download latest and then search for *.zip in zeronet folder to found it

Comment: You realise 127.0.0.1 is the networking shorthand for `me`?

Comment: @tetsujin Yes I know. But if you run ZeroNet client you can see that page

Comment: @tetsujin It is a zeronet address. If you run ZeroNet client you can also see that page